# Where is the file location for Minecraft: PE worlds on Android Marshmallow?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, android

I recently got a new phone. When getting rid of my old phone, I transferred all of my Minecraft world files via USB to my computer from the following folders:

*Internal storage > games > com.mojang > minecraftWorlds*

On my new phone,  I went to put the worlds in, but I couldn't find the *games* folder. When I searched, I couldn't find *com.mojang* either. The closest result was *Android > obb > com.mojang.minecraftpe*. This was an empty folder. My old phone had Android Lollipop (Moto e2). My new phone is Android Marshmallow (ZTE Prestige 2).

Where are the Minecraft worlds located on Android Marshmallow? I can't seem to find them.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/227246/how-can-i-backup-my-minecraft-pocket-edition-worlds) out yet:

Comment: Have you played Minecraft on that device yet? If you do, it should create all the necessary folders, then you can replace them.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. You have to go onto a world that you have on your new phone, go to settings, go to profile, then change the world save location from application to external. This creates the games>com.minecraft>minecraftWorlds files.

Answer (score 1):

You can export the worlds by using MCPE Internal World Extractor. The program works by using ADB's backup feature to copy all the Minecraft data from the device. The archived data is then extracted using AndroidBackupExtractor and the minecraftWorlds folder is moved from it.

More information and downloads can be found [here](https://tikolu.net/world-exporter).

Comment: If this is a tool you've created (from your username and the website URL it seems highly likely), you need to disclose that you are the creator. While this tool does sound useful, our site is pretty sensitive to spam and 'stealthy' advertisements that may or may not help the user.