# If I delete my Minecraft PE on my android how can I get the saves back?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to get my worlds back because my dad deleted the game!

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/227246/73976)

Answer (score 1):

They might be gone if the app was uninstalled.

If they still happen to be there, navigate to:

```
/sdcard0/games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds/...
```

If you have data there, transfer them to another device. If they're not there, I'm afraid you're out of luck.